# Синтаксис MySQL в функции как написать присвоение функции select

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как присвоить результат работы select по двум колонкам.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetP()
RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
  select id,P from P ORDER BY Use ASC limit 1;
return 0;
END
```

Подскажите как положить **id,P** получаемые значения в разные переменные что бы к ним можно было обратится?
Я пробывал делать что то вроде

```
@getId:=id,@getP:=P
```

Но это возвращает ошибку, как быть?

Comment: Используйте select into https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: И лучше не используйте переменные с `@` в функции, на них можно повлиять из вне. Нормальные переменные функции без `@` и объявляются с помощью declare

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет бесценен... он помог мне благодарю!